# Is there a Linux equivalent of Diskpart

Tags: linux, windows, diskpart

you know diskpart for windows? I wonder if there is something similar for Linux. Could you help me please? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating ext4 partition from console](http://superuser.com/questions/643765/creating-ext4-partition-from-console)

Comment: Try [GParted](http://gparted.org/).

Comment: diskpart is the command line Windows partitioning system... Linux has various terminal tools such as `fdisk`, `parted`. `GParted` is a graphical interface for `parted`. As the OP has asked about `diskpart` it may be best to provide command line answers for Linux...?

Comment: Sounds like parted ... I thought one-line, or here one-word, answers were frowned upon though... ah well, an answer's an answer

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use parted - or it's cooler more fun GUI gparted (I prefer gparted if given a choice).

Here's links to info on using parted:

- [gnu.org Parted User's Manual - 2. Using Parted](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_chapter/parted_2.html)
- [How to Create Partition on Linux for >2TB Size using Parted GPT](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/2tb-gtp-parted/)

Or

- [Wikihow How to Use Gparted](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Gparted) - with plenty of photos. If you're already running a linux with gparted installed (Ubuntu, Mint, etc) skip the first 2 steps